# Exporting rule from sentinel and then using azure devops to deploy ARM template

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager

My task is to deploy ARM template that has been exported from Sentinel. It looks like this:

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workspace": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/providers', parameters('workspace'), 'Microsoft.SecurityInsights'),'/alertRules/6db8cd19-9b27-4bf0-84f3-2111204460b9')]",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('workspace'),'/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/6db8cd19-9b27-4bf0-84f3-2111204460b9')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/providers/alertRules",
            "kind": "Scheduled",
            "apiVersion": "2022-11-01-preview",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "Informational rule 1",
                "description": "Rule to test ARM template deployment",
                "severity": "Medium",
                "enabled": true,
                "query": "AzureActivity\r\n| where OperationName == \"Create or Update Virtual Machine\" or OperationName ==\"Create Deployment\"\r\n| where ActivityStatus == \"Succeeded\"\r\n| make-series dcount(ResourceId)  default=0 on EventSubmissionTimestamp in range(ago(7d), now(), 1d) by Caller",
                "queryFrequency": "PT5H",
                "queryPeriod": "PT5H",
                "triggerOperator": "GreaterThan",
                "triggerThreshold": 0,
                "suppressionDuration": "PT5H",
                "suppressionEnabled": false,
                "startTimeUtc": null,
                "tactics": [],
                "techniques": [],
                "alertRuleTemplateName": null,
                "incidentConfiguration": {
                    "createIncident": true,
                    "groupingConfiguration": {
                        "enabled": false,
                        "reopenClosedIncident": false,
                        "lookbackDuration": "PT5H",
                        "matchingMethod": "AllEntities",
                        "groupByEntities": [],
                        "groupByAlertDetails": [],
                        "groupByCustomDetails": []
                    }
                },
                "eventGroupingSettings": {
                    "aggregationKind": "SingleAlert"
                },
                "alertDetailsOverride": null,
                "customDetails": null,
                "entityMappings": null,
                "sentinelEntitiesMappings": null,
                "templateVersion": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I was trying to use azurerm template :

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "template" {
    name = "template-deploy"
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    template_body = file("${path.module}/ARM_rule_templates/example_rule.json")
    deployment_mode = "Incremental"
    parameters =jsonencode({
        "workspace" = {value = data.azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics.name}
         })
}
```

Is it even possible to deploy that template from azure devops without adding something to it ? Do you have any thoughts how to move on? I am out of hope at this moment.
Regards,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to deploy the ARM template that has been exported by calling with the file URL and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

To deploy an ARM template that's been exported from Azure Sentinel using Azure DevOps, there are a few key steps and considerations to make. The ARM template you've provided is specifically for deploying an alert rule in Azure Sentinel.

The approach mentioned in the query was possible but the template used i.e.,
**`resource "azurerm_template_deployment"`**
was depreciation resource module which doesn't help in provisioning the requirement you are looking for. The resource **`resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment"`** will help.

However, the JSON shared in the query was missing with certain parameters we cannot achieve the requirement so I took a demo example JSON to demonstrate how this works.

**My JSON file for demonstration:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_ZRS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account type"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "storageAccountName": "[concat(uniquestring(resourceGroup().id), 'storage')]",
    "publicIPAddressName": "[concat('myPublicIp', uniquestring(resourceGroup().id))]",
    "publicIPAddressType": "Dynamic",
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "dnsLabelPrefix": "terraform-acctest"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "accountType": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
      "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressName')]",
      "location": "[variables('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "[variables('publicIPAddressType')]",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[variables('dnsLabelPrefix')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('storageAccountName')]"
    }
  }
}
```

**My Terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "core" {}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demovkr-rg"  # Update this to your desired resource group name
  location = "east us"
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-workspace"  # Update this to your desired workspace name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"  # Choose an appropriate SKU
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "template" {
  name                = "template-deploy"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  template_content      = file("/home/bolli/demo/demo.json")
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"

  parameters_content = jsonencode({
    "storageAccountType" = { value = "Standard_LRS" }  // Example parameter, adjust as needed
  })

  
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]